# Universal selector, how to exclude some elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

After building a blog last part is to make a universal selector that when hover over it will highlight the elements yellow. however we need to exclude elements like body and html from that behavior. 
i starter with this

```
*:hover { background-color:yellow }
```

How can I exclude elements from universal selector?

Comment: That would be a confusing website to use if you made everything under the pointer yellow, even not interactive portions.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to exclude root elements like `html`/`body`, you could select all elements *within* them.

In this case, any of the following would work:

```
html body *:hover { background-color: yellow }
```

```
body *:hover { background-color: yellow }
```

```
* * *:hover { background-color: yellow }
```

```
:root * *:hover { background-color: yellow }
```

---

To exclude other elements, you could use the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to negate them.

For instance, you could add an `.excluded` class to the elements.

```
html body *:not(.excluded):hover { background-color: yellow }
```

This will be problematic, though, because the universal selector will be applied to *all* elements, including elements nested within the `.excluded` elements.

If there are any nested elements within the `body` element, the `background-color` will inadvertently appear to be applied to children elements even if they contain the `.excluded` class merely because the `background-color` is added to the parent element.

You could consider using the direct child combinator, `>` to prevent this to a degree.

```
html body > *:not(.excluded):hover { background-color: yellow }
```

Of course, this assumes you only want the `background-color` applied to direct children in the `body` element.

In conclusion, you should therefore avoid using the universal selector when possible.

Comment: Of course, the `:not()` pseudo-class is not backward compatible with older Browsers, so the first example should be used. Either that or just override the CSS on elements you don't want to be yellow.

Comment: @PHPglue Browser support looks pretty good to me. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 1):

You almost never want to use the universal selector in your CSS.

If you wanted to exclude the `html` and `body` elements, you'd write your selector like `body * {}`.

Comment: Yeah i figured this much, but thats what hw asked for so i have to do it this way for now.